# Problem bridging two networks with Ubiquiti hardware

Tags: wireless, bridge

I want to bridge two networks using a Powerstation 5 22V and a Nanobridge M5 from Ubiquiti but I'm having serious problems with it. Here's a small doodle describing how the network looks like:

[image: Network Diagram]

Now here's the thing. From my PC, I'm able to ping both Ubiquiti antennas, but I'm not able to ping the Router. But from the Router, I can only ping the Nanobridge - pinging the Powerstation keeps failing.
From my PC I'm even able to SSH into the Nanobridge and ping the Router from there. What I need is to get a connection to the Router from my PC.

Here is the network config of both antennas.
Nanobridge:

[image: Nanobridge Screenshot]

Powerstation:

[image: Powerstation Screenshot]

Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: To start with, it looks like you have the Powerstation configured to use the Nanostation as it's L3 gateway, when you are using the devices in L2 (bridge) mode.  All devices should be using your router as their L3 gateway.  Could you include the wireless configuration and bridge table from both devices?

Comment: Highly possible, problem in Wireless configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works now, all I had to do is to switch the wireless mode on each antenna from Station to AP and vice versa and set their IP-Address to DHCP. I still don't understand why it had to do with the Wireless Mode (Access Point/Station). Can anyone explain this to me please?

Comment: Please don't ask additional question in answers.  As for what you have done, you are  no longer bridging the connection, and I still believe if you had provided the outputs I requested, we could have found the actual problem.  Most likely, you were missing settings elsewhere that needed correction for bridging to work.